# i have a responsive map which i can't zoom

Tags: jquery, html, google-maps, responsive-design

I have a Google map with custom markers. I had to set `map.fitBounds(bounds);` so that all of the markers can be seen when the page is loaded. But now when I try to zoom it, it doesn't zoom and also the infowindow gets cropped when clicked. So what is the solution for this.

This is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cancerian73/48jTZ/5/)

```
.map-container{margin:0}
#map{min-height:500px;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Autocenter function you are using uses Fitbounds, which means the view will fit so it shows all the markers. When your zoom has finished, the map goes idle. Seeing as you have added an eventlistener to the idle event, it will run the Autocenter function.

Remove that function or remove the idle-listener and you're set.